# Error log, reason why my server crashed

Tags: debian, logging

```
[Fri Aug 05 05:54:44 2011] [error] [client 88.190.231.199] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
[Fri Aug 05 06:20:14 2011] [error] [client 72.14.176.176] File does not exist: /var/www/connect.facebook.net, referer: http://www.mysite.com/
[Fri Aug 05 06:24:44 2011] [error] [client 69.171.229.246] File does not exist: /var/www/images
[Fri Aug 05 06:35:04 2011] [error] [client 173.29.117.113] File does not exist: /var/www/Fforum
[Fri Aug 05 06:38:57 2011] [error] [client 91.194.219.139] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
[Fri Aug 05 06:39:41 2011] [error] [client 91.194.219.139] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
[Fri Aug 05 06:49:41 2011] [error] [client 119.92.155.52] File does not exist: /var/www/...
[Fri Aug 05 07:01:14 2011] [error] [client 91.194.219.139] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
[Fri Aug 05 07:03:35 2011] [warn] child process 24958 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24694 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24978 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24227 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25007 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 23427 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24633 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24854 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25008 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24796 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24644 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24824 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24697 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24277 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25009 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24645 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24554 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24178 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25010 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24698 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 23553 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24557 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25067 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24799 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25079 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 23626 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24650 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24699 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24652 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25085 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24595 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25087 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24904 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24598 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25088 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25094 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24905 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 23252 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24906 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25095 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 23253 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24602 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24830 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24911 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24912 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24605 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24915 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 24917 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25103 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25110 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25111 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25112 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25115 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25118 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25124 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25127 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25129 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25130 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25133 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:13 2011] [warn] child process 25134 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:15 2011] [warn] child process 25166 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25140 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25142 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25150 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25152 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25154 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25156 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25159 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25160 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25161 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25162 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25163 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25166 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25167 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25169 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25170 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25178 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25179 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25182 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25183 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25187 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25192 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25195 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25196 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25204 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25206 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25207 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25212 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25213 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25214 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25217 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25219 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25229 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25230 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25231 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25232 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25234 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24958 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24694 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24978 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24227 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25007 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 23427 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24633 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24796 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24644 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24824 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24697 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24277 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25009 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24645 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24554 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24178 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25010 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 23553 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24557 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25067 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24799 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25079 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 23626 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24650 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24699 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24652 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25085 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24595 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25087 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24904 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24598 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25088 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25094 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24905 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 23252 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24906 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25095 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 23253 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24602 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24830 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24911 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24912 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24915 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 24917 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25103 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25111 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25112 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25115 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25118 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25124 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25127 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25129 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25130 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25162 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25163 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25166 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25167 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25169 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25170 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25178 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25187 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25192 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25195 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25196 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25204 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25206 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25207 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25212 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25213 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25214 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25217 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25219 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25230 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25231 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25232 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25234 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

There was a lot of more SIGTERM error, had to remove half of them because of the character limit.
Anyone can tell me what the warning means and how to avoid server crash?

Comment: In your config files, did you tell it to start a ridiculous amount of children or workers? That's the only thing I can think of. Sorry if this isn't enough of a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Fri Aug 05 05:54:44 2011] [error] [client 88.190.231.199] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
[Fri Aug 05 06:38:57 2011] [error] [client 91.194.219.139] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
[Fri Aug 05 06:39:41 2011] [error] [client 91.194.219.139] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
```

Looks like someone is probing your server with [DFind](http://heapoverflow.com/f0rums/projects/tools/20-dfind-port-scanner/). But Apache rejected this request because the hostname is missing.

You can use `iptables` with `string` module to drop it:

```
iptables -A INPUT -d <your_server_IP> -p tcp --dport 80 -m string -algo bm --string '/w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.' -j DROP
```

You should limit the offset to searching with `--from` and `--to` (do it with `tcpdump` on the server and open by Wireshark).

```
[warn] child process 24958 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
```

This means that the child processes were not terminated and a SIGnal TERMinate was sent. **Is there any other errors in error_log**?

```
[error] child process 25140 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
```

Force kill the child process immediately.

```
[error] could not make child process 25234 exit, attempting to continue anyway
```

The process hung for some reason and could not be kill.

Answer (score 0):

If processes cannot be killed, even by a `SIGKILL`, it means that they're hung on some uninterruptible I/O.  There are gradually less and less of these (NFS used to be one, but not any more), so you really should be stracing your hung processes and checking dmesg for hints as to what could be going on.  None of them are what you'd call "normal operation".

Answer (score 0):

These messages look like the system is deliberately shutting down:

```
[Fri Aug 05 07:03:35 2011] [warn] child process 24958 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:16 2011] [error] child process 25170 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [error] could not make child process 25234 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Fri Aug 05 07:04:17 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

As the system shuts down, it's killing every process, trying first with TERM, then KILL, then just moving on; the last item shows that syslog was killed.

This is not a case of overheating or out of memory or locking on a file system mount - something specifically sent a shutdown.